# R survminer 95%CI estimation method

Tags: r, sas, survival-analysis, survminer

A vendor that we work with is attempting to replicate my KM estimates/curves, including 95%CIs. I code in R while they code in SAS. I am using the `survminer` package in R and the `surv_median` function to derive my 95%CIs. They will be utilizing the `PROC LIFETEST` procedure.

I tried searching through the package documentation (link: [survminer documenation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survminer/survminer.pdf)) but couldn't find anything useful.

Any assistance determining the CI estimation methodology is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the package source code itself?

Comment: (This is not really a coding question, therefore voting to close since you are essentially asking us to read the code and find relevant documentation.) Typically survminer functions are ggplotting wraps  around the `survival` package. You should look at the code for the (unstated) plotting functions you are using and then refer to the documentation for the corresponding survival based functions.

Comment: Thanks. I posted on Stats Exchange and they said to post here since it is related to R.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  I have dug into the documentation for both the `survminer` and `survival`  packages multiple times and still cannot find the information I need.